# Change or Create a component with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm learning react and I'm still confused about the way we have to build and modify components.
I'm working on the UI registration part of my project and I want a specific component in the case where the user is actually registred or not.

I have created a boolean attribute in each of this case using `useState` and from what I've read, I've got a `useEffect` to allow me to check the latest status of my first hook. So if it's true it means the user is well created in DB, from this I want to create (or modify) a component which will be telling to the user if he is well registred on the app.

```
const [signinStatus, setsigninStatus] = useState(false);

useEffect( () => { 
  if (signinStatus === true) {
    console.log(signinStatus);}
  
}, [signinStatus]);
```

Can I create or modify a component inside my `useEffect` hook or am I going in the wrong direction?

Answer (score 0):

you could use signinStatus value directly and conditional rendering together for this goal. there is no need to modify anything in useEffect.

```
const [signinStatus, setsigninStatus] = useState(false);


return <>

   {
       sigingStatus ? <SomeComponent/> : <AnotherComponent/>
   }

</>
```

Answer (score 0):

**useState** : This keeps some data & helps in re-rendering. Whenever it changes, component rerenders.

**useEffect** : This is the function that is called when component is initially rendered or any of the dependency provided in the second parameter in the function changes.

---

What you can do is

```
function LoginUser(){
   const [signinStatus, setsigninStatus] = useState(false);

   useEffect( () => { 
     if (signinStatus === true) {
        console.log(signinStatus);}
   }, [signinStatus]);

   return <div>{signinStatus===true ? <p>User is logged in</p> : <p>User is not logged in</p>}</div>
}
```